# Can you use a TempVar in MS Access VBA linking to a element on an sub-report

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have created an Access report, with a sub report.

When emailing the report, the email button on the report removes the "sample" watermark before emailing a PDF copy. My VBA works fine on the main report, but I'm struggling to get it working on the sub-report when not hard-coding the report name.

The main report shows pages 1 and 2, the sub-report is for page 3 (p3).

The following is working to hide the watermark on the sub-report:

```
Me.rptTermsReport1_p3.Report.imgSample3.Visible = False
```

Since I have about 40 reports, I don't want to hard-code the sub-report names, but use a TempVar for the report name (e.g. rptTermsReport1 & append (_p3)

I have tried the following (and a few variations), but the TempVars and the concatenated _p3 is not working:

```
Report ("[TempVars]![ReportName]" & "_p3") & .imgSample3.Visible = False
```

The error is: "Compile error: invalid or unqualified reference" and it's the [reportname] that's highlighted.
Any ideas how you can use a TempVar with a concatenated string (_p3) linking to a field on a sub-report?

Answer (score 2):

Don't put `""` around variables.

`.<Control>` mustn't be concatenated, but used directly.

To access a variable report, use the `Reports` collection

If these aren't subreports, this should work:

```
Reports([TempVars]![ReportName] & "_p3")!imgSample3.Visible = False
```

If they are subreports, see: 
[Refer to Form and Subform properties and controls](http://access.mvps.org/access/forms/frm0031.htm)

(just replace `Forms` by `Reports`)

Comment: Thanks for the pointer Andre!
Managed to get it working with: 
`Me([TempVars]![ReportName] & "_p3").Report!imgSample3.Visible = False`